# VS 2010: Class diagram with xml summary description?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, diagram, class-diagram

using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate I created a class diagram of a C# / WPF project. The project is well documented, meaning ever property has a xml summary. Now in the class diagram one can hover over a property and read this summary - fine. But what about printing? Visual Studio just prints the diagram! Is there any way to let Visual Studio 2010 add the summary for the properties? Are there tools that an do this? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Use the modeling tools addin. This allows you to add the comments to the diagram. http://modeling.codeplex.com/releases/view/49473